# To Remove from action file name in url usign php

Tags: php, url

Hello every one i am new in this concept of URL rewriting. i have url as like that 
 "http://localhost/htaccess/formname/my-parameter-value"

but i want to as like that 
"http://localhost/htaccess/my-parameter-value" 

  **thanks in advance 

here is my code**

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On     
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?name=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?name=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]     

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?name=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)?$ $1.php?name=$2 [L,QSA]
```